# Battle-hardened strategy for naming files and folders in asp.net mvc projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In French, a "donkey bridge" is some apparent difficulty in a subject to be learnt that throws off newcomers - the donkeys. The expression is used with patronizing assurance by educators who know the difficulty is apparent, not real, and the donkeys just have to cross the bridge.

Well I'm the donkey, and I'm having real trouble settling down with the folder structure and "virtual" urls of asp.net mvc projects. Urls are now a blend of pseudo-path information, encoded in routes, and arguments, that resolve to controller classes that, being classes, have no notion of their directory. So, it seems, there is no simple way of using relative paths/urls to reference static resources associated with a dynamic page: script file, stylesheet, razor view, images. .Net helpfully gives me default search locations for views, and default folders for "Content", "Scripts", "Images". I get the feeling they want me to file things by type. But this obliges me to invent file and subfolder names in each of these locations, then to hardcode the resulting paths in the controller and the view. Since a given controller generally has only a handful of tightly coupled views, and 99.9% of views have 1 script file and 1 stylesheet, all this name invention, and categorization by type, introduces needless brittleness and complexity, and masks any expression of what the project actually does.

Is anyone else fighting this? Is their a tried-and-tested strategy for naming in large mvc projects that

- [Expresses what the project does at the top level of the folder structure](http://youtu.be/Nsjsiz2A9mg) (or any level of the folder structure!).
- Provides a default location or generated names for .cshtml, .js and .css, such that I don't need to search through code to find the names of associated  resources.
- Preserves the flexibility and decoupling of naming/indirection where this has proved useful.

I'm aware of **[areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx)** as a way subdividing an mvc project into functional groupings, but this just seems to recreate the problem inside each area. I've looked at [this method for](http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/) customizing the search location for views, but there's no dynamic element. I've [implemented a view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location) to have fine-grained run-time control over the view path, which is fine if you're brave but I'm still unsure how best to use it, and I'm put off by the potential caching issues. For all the dissing of opinions, I'm particularly interested in answers addressing what I *should* do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the downvoters, intolerant village folk. The donkeys that refused to cross the bridge are **right**, and they're all hanging out in a green field, munching happily on [**Nancy**](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjntNfwwbHMAhWoL8AKHcL5CQ8QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnancyfx.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFISeUdKg6ZrK8eVU_h8lK-njTuKg&sig2=fix8_YM8lSicgnKzT2Az5w) and building fabulous Owin pipelines. [**Feature folders**](http://fr.slideshare.net/Anthony_Steele_/feature-folders) are the future.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that trying to arrange elements by type is usually problematic. For example putting C# interfaces for a customer and a product in the same "Interfaces" folder is not something I am keen on personally, I'd rather have a Customers folder and a Products folder, each with an Interfaces folder inside.

However, with MVC, there is a lot of enforced and unenforced convention in place which you will probably have to live with. As an example, if you have a controller called ProductContoller, it will automatically look for views in the Views\Product folder. So your product index.aspx/cshtml view is nicely segmented from your other index views.

For things like scripts and CSS, these are not enforced and technically you could put them anywhere, but it's a convention across many web frameworks to keep them in the same root folder. In some frameworks you would be explicitly allowing public access to certain folders to read files, so you'd want to do this for all scripts or CSS files together.

It's not an answer but I hope it helps.

Comment: Over the bridge i go then. Whipped and dragged.

Answer (score 0):

> then to hardcode the resulting paths in the controller and the view

No.

Use `UrlHelper` (`Url` property in controllers and views). Extends it with ad-hoc functions for resolving your specific urls, as [this blog post do](http://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/6-aspnet-mvc-urlhelper-quick-tips-to-maximize-your-link-management-Q5).

For resolving views, stick to MVC conventions as explained in [Dorian's answer](/a/35706184/1178314).